# cancel class not working for submitHandler to ignore button click

Tags: jquery, submit, validation

Got these two image buttons:

```
<input type="image" src="images/Update.png" name="btnSubmit" value="Update"/>
<input type="image" src="images/Cancel.png" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" class="cancel" onclick="hide_edit_div()" />
```

Now, even clicking on the Cancel button runs the submithandler. How do I modify it to ignore it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(this.forms[4]) {
    $("#editTaskInfo").validate({
        rules:{"task_title": {required: true},
               "task_instr": {required: true},
               "task_desc" : {required: true}
                },
       submitHandler: function(form) {
         var postData = $('#editTaskInfo').serialize();
         $.ajax({type: "POST",
                 url: "post_task.php",
                 data: postData,
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {
                   if(textStatus == 'success') {
                     $("div.error span").html(data.msg);
                     $("div.error img").hide();
                     $("div.error").show();
                     $("#static_task_price").text(data.price);
                     $("#static_title").text(data.title);
                     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
                     hide_edit_div();
                     $("div.error").fadeOut(10000);
                   }
                 },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   $("div.error span").html(errorThrown);
                   $("div.error img").show();
                   $("div.error").show();
                 }
         });
       }
    }
    );
  }
});
```

Edit: (since I can't answer my own for 8 hrs, **what a stupid restriction**)

Modified the second button to be a div like this:

```
<div id="btnCancel" style="float:right; cursor:pointer; width:50px; height:20px; background-image: url(images/Cancel.png); " onclick="hide_edit_div()">&nbsp;</div>
```

Now, if I can only get it positioned correctly. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you use simply:

```
<img src="images/Cancel.png" id="btnCancel" onclick="hide_edit_div()" />
```

Comment: Nope, still goes into the submitHandler.

Comment: @MB34 See my answer as to why this is happening and suggested fixes.

Comment: @MB34 see that i changed <input to <img

Comment: As you can ss from my edit, I used a div and it works as planned.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `cancel` class will only [bypass the validation and will not stop the actual submission](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Skipping_validation_on_submit). You'll  need to handle that part elsewhere. Possible work-arounds :

1. Change the type of the `Cancel` button so that it does not trigger the submit anymore.
2. Trigger the form submission yourself, only when the correct button is clicked - see [JQuery Validate - class="cancel" submit button only stops validation once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850662/jquery-validate-class-cancel-submit-button-only-stops-validation-once/2858954#2858954)

Answer (score -1):

Change the type of the Cancel button like this;

```
<input class="cancel" type="button" id="close" value="Cancel" />
```

Comment: The author of the question wants to use the "image" type and not the "button" type, so this is not an answer.